# DataGridViews not showing on form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a form that contains a few DataGridViews.  In the Form's Load event, I create DataTables and bind the DataGridView DataSources to those tables, like so (for example):

```
    newObject.Environment = New DataSet
    tblTemps = New DataTable("Temp")
    tblTemps.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(Date))
    tblTemps.Columns.Add("Temp (F)", GetType(Single))
    newObject.Environment.Tables.Add(tblTemps)
    dgvTemp.DataSource = newObject.Environment.Tables("Temp")
```

In design, the DataGridViews have AllowUserToAddRows and AllowUserToDeleteRows set to True.  So what I would expect is that when this form loads, dgvTemp will show a grid with the 2 columns and 1 empty 'New' row.

But this is not what is happening - the grids are completely empty. Any ideas why?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Note I set the data source to the tables in that fashion because I want the user to be able to enter data in the grids and have the data tables be updated accordingly.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the first line and ensure that whatever `newObject` is, it is initialized (isnt Nothing).  If you encounter an NRE in form load, VS can often swallow the exception.

Comment: If after steps advised by @Plutonix, `DataGridView` will be still empty, then check that `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true`

Answer (score 0):

I took both Plutonix's and Fabio's suggestions - it's true, I was not initializing newObject before that block, and I added the `.AutoGenerateColumns = True` just to be sure.  Now it works!  Thank you very much!